# Mathematics of MC Escher

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

I'm working with an undergraduate math major McNair Scholar, whose had our 10 week 'Group Theory for High School Teachers' class and will start our year long Abstract Algebra sequence in the fall.

I'm looking for an independent study reading project for him that might also reinforce what he's learned and prepare him to learn more.  Can anyone suggest an undergrad level book or expository paper about the classification of wallpaper groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"[The Symmetries of Things](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568812205)" by Conway et al has some really interesting material at different levels including wallpaper groups, and also some examples (and great illustrations) which could be used in a high school or maths club.

Comment: @Barry Cipra - thanks for the edit

Comment: You're welcome.  I had the link in hand because I was going to post it in an answer myself.  You saved me the trouble.

Comment: Thanks, this looks very promising!